# Why does `is_same` in the C++ PyTorch API fail when comparing with the same tensor that is read from a file?

Tags: pytorch, libtorch

Why does `torch::Tensor::is_same` fail the following assertion? A tensor is written to a file using the C++ PyTorch API, then read again into another tensor, and `is_same` compares both tensors:

```
torch::Tensor x_sequence = torch::linspace(0, M_PI, 1000);    
torch::save(x_sequence, "x_sequence.dat");
torch::Tensor x_read;
torch::load(x_read, "x_sequence.dat");
assert(x_read.is_same(x_sequence));
```

This results in:

```
int main(int, char**): Assertion `x_read.is_same(x_sequence)' failed.
```

using

- python-pytorch, version 1.6.0-2 on Arch Linux
- g++ (GCC) 10.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torch::Tensor::is_same(const torch::Tensor& other)`is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b2e52186b93b786b1ed812179804fd2496c6efd1/caffe2/core/tensor.h). It is important to notice that a `Tensor` is actually a pointer on an underlying `TensorImpl` class (which actually holds the data).

Thus, when you call `is_same`, what is checked is actually whether or not your pointers are the same, i.e whether your 2 tensors are pointing to the same underlying memory. Here is a very simple example to understand it well :

```
auto x = torch::randn({4,4});
auto copy = x;
auto clone = x.clone();
std::cout << x.is_same(copy) << " " << x.is_same(clone) << std::endl;
>>> 0 1
```

Here, the call to `clone` forces pytorch to copy the data in another memory location. Consequently, the pointers are different and `is_same` returns false.

If you want to actually compare the values, you have no choice but to compute the difference between the two tensors and compute how close to 0 this difference is.